# Why is my Bootstrap nav toggle button is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My Bootstrap nav toggle button is not working.

What is wrong in my code? Why it is not working?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0077)https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/phoenixassets/web-frameworks/index.html -->
<html lang="en"><head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=windows-1252">
        <title>Ristorante Con Fusion</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
     <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ristorante Con Fusion</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">                 
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </nav>  
    <header class="jumbotron">


        <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row row-header">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                    <h1>Ristorante con Fusion</h1>
                    <p style="padding:40px;"></p>
                    <p>We take inspiration from the World's best cuisines, and create a unique fusion experience. Our lipsmacking creations will tickle your culinary senses!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-content">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-sm-push-9">
                <p style="padding:20px;"></p>
                <h3 align="center">Our Lipsmacking Culinary Creations</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-sm-pull-3">
                <h2>Uthappizza</h2>
                <p>A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.</p>
                <p><a href="https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/phoenixassets/web-frameworks/index.html#">More ?</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row row-content">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-sm-push-9">
                <p style="padding:20px;"></p>
                <h3 align="center">This Month's Promotions</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-sm-pull-3">
                <h2>Weekend Grand Buffet</h2>
                <p>Featuring mouthwatering combinations with a choice of five different salads, six enticing appetizers, six main entrees and five choicest desserts. Free flowing bubbly and soft drinks. All for just $19.99 per person </p>
                <p><a href="https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/phoenixassets/web-frameworks/index.html#">More ?</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row row-content">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-sm-push-9">
                <p style="padding:20px;"></p>
                <h3 align="center">Meet our Culinary Specialists</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-sm-pull-3">
                <h2>Alberto Somayya</h2>
                <h4>Executive Chef</h4>
                <p>Award winning three-star Michelin chef with wide International experience having worked closely with whos-who in the culinary world, he specializes in creating mouthwatering Indo-Italian fusion experiences. </p>
                <p><a href="https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/phoenixassets/web-frameworks/index.html#">More ?</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="row-footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">             
                <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <h5>Links</h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><a href="https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/phoenixassets/web-frameworks/index.html#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/phoenixassets/web-frameworks/index.html#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/phoenixassets/web-frameworks/index.html#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/phoenixassets/web-frameworks/index.html#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-5">
                    <h5>Our Address</h5>
                    <address>
                      121, Clear Water Bay Road<br>
                      Clear Water Bay, Kowloon<br>
                      HONG KONG<br>
                      Tel.: +852 1234 5678<br>
                      Fax: +852 8765 4321<br>
                      Email: <a href="mailto:confusion@food.net">confusion@food.net</a>
                   </address>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                    <div style="padding: 40px 10px;">
                        <a href="http://google.com/+">Google+</a>
                        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=">Facebook</a>
                        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/">LinkedIn</a>
                        <a href="http://twitter.com/">Twitter</a>
                        <a href="http://youtube.com/">YouTube</a>
                        <a href="mailto:">Mail</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <p style="padding:10px;"></p>
                    <p align="center">? Copyright 2015 Ristorante Con Fusion</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: If you're seeing any errors in the console, please add them up. I'm guessing there's something wrong with your libs, why don't you try using a different version or using a cdn just like you did with jquery?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What behaviour are you (not) seeing? We need a better problem statement than this.

Answer (score 0):

Hope so below solution work for you, may be problem is in loading some external library, when you open this page in browser, go to console of browser using F12, see is there any errors or not?

I have created **[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yashsoni789/bozoboto/)** 
and in its your nav toggle button is working, but some links inside it like Home, Menu, About not working, because you did not specify links in `<a href="#">`.